# jUnit, Mockito. How to ensure a method in abstract class (a templae method) invokes the abstract hook method?

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

Here I go:

```
abstract class IdentifiedEntity<E extends IdentifiedEntity> implements Cloneable {
  ...
  public void updateWith(E that) {
    if (this != that) {
      if (that.isNew()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot update with a new entity");
      }
      if (this.isNew()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot update a new entity");
      }
      if (this.getId() != that.getId()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("IDs do not match");
      }
      doUpdateWith(that);
    }
  }

  abstract void doUpdateWith(E that);
  ...
}

public final class User extends IdentifiedEntity<User> {
  ...
  @Override
  void doUpdateWith(User that) {
    assert that != null;
    this.name = that.name;
    this.email = that.email;
    System.arraycopy(that.password, 0, password, 0, password.length);
    this.enabled = that.enabled;
    this.caloriesPerDayLimit = that.caloriesPerDayLimit;
  }
  ...
}
```

The question is how can I unit test the `updateWith(...)` to ensure that it definely invokes the abstract `doUpdateWith(...)` implmented in the descendant (yes, for sure,if i tpasse sall the checks)?

That you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @CoronA, I found the answer. Here it is:

```
@Test
public void updateWith() {
  User user = this.user.clone().setId(100);
  User mock = Mockito.spy(user);
  mock.updateWith(user);
  Mockito.verify(mock).doUpdateWith(user);
}
```

Thank you guys a lot!!!

Comment: If it was helpful, than accepting my answer would be kind ;).

Answer (score 1):

Create a dummy sub class

```
class ConcreteEntity extends IdentifiedEntity<ConcreteEntity> {
  @Override
  void doUpdateWith(ConcreteEntity that) {
  }
}
```

then test like this:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    ConcreteEntity e = Mockito.spy(new ConcreteEntity());
    e.updateWith(e);

    Mockito.verify(e).doUpdateWith(e);
}
```

However such a test is very special. It does not allow you to change implementation of your method.

Comment: The principle is sound, but this way it doesn't work: `verify` only works on movies instances. The dummy subclasses needs to keep a counter for how often the methods are called.

Comment: These snippets are not only an idea, they do actually work! Try out yourself. They fail if `IndentifiedEntity` does not call update, and succeed if it calls update.

Comment: Oh, I missed the `Mockito.spy`, that's actually the important bit about this. In fact, with this you don't even need the concrete class; you can just do `sut = Mockito.spy(IdentifiedEntity.class); sut.updateWith(sut); verify(sut).doUpdateWith(sut);`.

Comment: You are right, but it is not very intuitive, since IdentifiedEntity is abstract. Mockito does a lot magic to get it work. Should I update my example?

Comment: I guess I'd add a comment to make it somewhat clearer, and add the "pure spy" as an alternative.